# Send command through serial port to electro-pneumatic regulator in C#

Tags: c#, serial-port, ascii, port

I have a programmable electro-pneumatic regulator and i need to communicate with it through serial port, i have never done things like that befire. The operation manual shows some instructions to communicate with it. These are the following:

```
Specification
==============
Comm. type
  Master/slave type
Synchronous type
  Asynchronous type
Comm. speed
  9,600[bps]
Start bit
  1[bit]
Data length
  8[bit]
Stop bit
  1[bit]
Parity bit
  N/A
Flow control
  N/A
Command end code
  CR・LF
Character-code
  ASCII
```

I have successfully connect it with the pc, but when im trying to control it and send the command the communication LED lights but it does not set the pressure. I think the problem will be with the command end code or the character code. The command sample is: send `"SET 614"`(its working range is 0-1023). I use the recommended specifications(comm speed,start bit etc.) in variables(just to be multifunctional). The program closes the port when you close the UI form.

```
  private void ComunicateComport() 
        {
            comtimer.Stop();
            Global.Refreshtime = Global.Refreshrate;
            comtimer.Start();
            SerialPort ComPort = new SerialPort(Global.COMPort,Global.Baudrate,Parity.None,Global.Databits,StopBits.One); 
            if (ComPort.IsOpen == false)
            {
                ComPort.Open();
            }
            Global.Error = 0;
            ComPort.DiscardOutBuffer();
            ComPort.WriteLine("SET 100"); 

        }
```

Comment: Have you tried replacing `ComPort.WriteLine` with `ComPort.Write` explicitely adding the CR/LF characters to the string?

Comment: Should i use it in the same line like:
ComPort.Write("SET 100\r\n");
Or seperated?
ComPort.Write("SET 100");
ComPort.Write("\r");
ComPort.Write("\n");

Answer (score 1):

Don't use WriteLine replace it with use ComPort.Write(String) and then send explicitly < CR > < LF > as end of your command string with byte array using  ComPort.Write({0x0D, 0x0A}, 0, 2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but ComPort.Write({0x0D, 0x0A}, 0, 2) occures errors: No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments and many } and ; expected. Could you please correct it? I dont know the semantics of that function.

Comment: basically you need to try this with correct syntax ComPort.Write(new  byte[] {0x0D, 0x0A}, 0, 2); according to documentation there is overload method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.write?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Ports_SerialPort_Write_System_Byte___System_Int32_System_Int32_

Comment: If @ZaheerAhmed's answer does not work on its own, also check if you need `\0` character at the end of your value to terminate it.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, we step forward to solve the problem, the communication seems to be OK, but the reduktor doesnt work properly. It makes a sound like a buzzer, may be the problem is in the command character coding?